# Difference between ASP.NET web API and RESTful WCF on performance basis

Tags: wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

What is a difference between ASP.NET web API and RESTful WCF.
Which of the service will be capable of handling two-way huge traffic, eats up less data and efficiency/performance wrt server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are well versed with MVC concepts, go for Asp.Net web Api, else use the REST WCF Http services. Performance wise both doesnt have any differences.